# Saving qgraph doesnt work in for loop, but outside

Tags: r, r-qgraph

I am trying to create and save multiple plots with `qgraph()`. So far I tried:

```
for (i in 1:100){
    png(paste(i,".png",sep="_"))
    qgraph(l[[i]])
    dev.off()
}
```

`l` is a list of 100 weight matrices.

Creating a plot outside of the for loop works without problems.

The for loop also works with with `plot()`, instead of `qgraph()`.

Alternatively I used:

```
qgraph.animate(l,progress=FALSE)
```

Using `qgraph.animate()` creates 100 plots. Is there a way of saving them? This would also have the benefit of being able to use constraint argument.

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your problem, but `paste(i,".png",sep="_")` returns strings like `"1_.png"`, is that what you were expecting?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine for now. I will change it into more meaningful names, once the loop is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my own question.
It takes two steps to get there.

1. Create and save list of plots:

   tert1_aggr_dates_coef_qgraph<-qgraph.animate(l,progress=F, constraint = .1)
2. Use list of plots in for loop, to create and save plots.

   for(i in 1:100){

   jpeg(paste(i,".jpg"))

   qgraph(tert1_aggr_dates_coef_qgraph[[i]])

   dev.off()}